# blend parameterized and programmatic unit tests

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

With JUnit you can use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` to provide a set of parameters to pass to the test constructor and then run tests with each object.

I'm trying to move as much test logic as possible into data, but there are some tests that won't easily be converted into data-driven tests. Is there a way to use JUnit's `Parameterized` runner to run some tests with parameters, and then also add non-data-driven tests that aren't run repeatedly for each test object construction?

Comment: What's wrong with having 2 test classes?  One for the parameterized, one for the non-parameterized?

Comment: I would rather put tests for one class in one test, instead of creating "MyClassDataDrivenTest" and "MyClassProgrammaticTest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround for this was to create a single class and place the programmatic and data-driven tests in two separate sub-classes. A sub-class must be static for JUnit to run its tests. Here's a skeleton:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class) // needed for working well with Ant
public class MyClassTests {
    public static class Programmatic {
        @Test
        public void myTest(){
            // test something here
        }
    }

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class DataDriven {
        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> getParams() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        private String data;
        public DataDriven(String testName, String data){
            this.data = data;
        }
        @Test
        public void test() throws AnalyzeExceptionEN{
            // test data string here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use Junit's `Enclosed` runner. it's very verbose but also pretty powerful. it allows you to combine multiple different runners in one file.

other option is to use custom junit runner. for sure zohhak supports [tests with parameters and without](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/1.1.1/Quick-Start.md#out-of-the-box). small extract:

```
@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class CoercingTest {

    @TestWith("ONE_OF_ENUM_VALUES")
    public void should_coerce_enum(SampleEnum param) {
        assertThat(param).isEqualTo(SampleEnum.ONE_OF_ENUM_VALUES);     
    }

    @Test
    public void should_run_standard_junit_test() {
        //this will also work
    }
}
```

if it's not enough for you, for sure you can find other runners that support both kind of tests.